# Meteor router returns Exception from Deps recompute: undefined

Tags: meteor, router, meteorite

I'm trying to redirect a page when a user logged in. However, I kept hitting this exception.

> Exception from Deps recompute: undefined

//login.js

```
  Template.loginForm.events({
  'click button#loginAdmin':
    function() {
        Session.set('user', 'test');
        alert(Session.get('user'));
    }
  });
```

//route.js

```
Meteor.Router.add({
    '/': 'userPage',    
    '/admin': function() {
      alert('route: ' + typeof Session.get('user'));
    if (typeof (Session.get('user')) !== 'undefined') {
        return 'adminPage';
      } else {
        return 'loginPage';
      }
    },
    '/poll': 'pollPage',
    '/ustream' : 'streamPage'
  })

  // to determine which page to render
  Template.body.helpers({
    layoutName: function() {
      switch (Meteor.Router.page()) {
        case 'adminPage':
          alert('in admin');
          return 'adminLayout';
        case 'userPage':
          return 'userLayout';
        case 'pollPage':
          return 'pollLayout';
        case 'streamPage':
          return 'streamLayout';
        case 'loginPage':
          return 'loginLayout';
        default:
          return 'userLayout';
      }
    }
  });
```

Even if I put Meteor.Router.to('/admin'); after i set session in login.js it still doesn't route to adminLayout. Instead it hit the above error.

Any solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you have the switch. When you're adding the routes the second part is the template. So for '/': 'userPage' when a person visits your root directory they are shown the userPage template.  I feel like it's trying to render the layout but the layoutName might be undefined the way you are doing it.  You should have {{renderPage}} where you want Router to select the template for you.

EDIT:

Ok, I think you should have the route as normal then and add a filter.

```
Meteor.Router.add({
    '/': 'userPage',    
    '/admin': 'adminPage',
    '/poll': 'pollPage',
    '/ustream' : 'streamPage'
  })

Meteor.Router.filters({
    'mustLogin': function(page) {
        if(typeof (Session.get('user')) !== 'undefined) {
            return page;
        } else {
            return 'loginPage';
        }
});

Meteor.Router.filter('mustLogin', {only: 'adminPage'});
```

Comment: Hi, actually I have {{renderPage}} somewhere. the pages rendered perfectly for other pages but not for the admin login page.

Comment: it still have the same problem. I suspecting that it was try to route it again while loading that causes the problem. any idea how i can stop it for routing again while loading?